# "Invalid Request" on Appcelerator Compile

Tags: appcelerator

I am using **Appcelerator Studio, build: 4.8.1.201612050850** and when i try to run on iPhone 6s simulator i am getting the error below. I am using **XCode Version 8.3.2 (8E2002)**

Error:

> Appcelerator Platform
>
> ## 502
>
> ---
>
> Bad Gateway
>
> ---
>
> Dashboard
>
> Status
>
> Get Help

I have tried "appc logout" and "appc login" several times but nothing changed.

How can i fix this ?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make sure your Ti SDK version is latest in your tiapp.xml file then try this following command via the terminal.

```
sudo npm install -g appcelerator

appc use latest

appc logout -D

appc login

appc setup
```

Then open Appcelerator Studio and try to run it.

Comment: OP's problem has nothing to do with a SDK version... As said it's a bad gateway so there's something wrong with IP communication between OP and the Appcelerator servers.